Android Compose M3 Button theming
Using Compose and Material3, can I theme buttons (or any other item)? For example, can I set the text color of buttons globally directly in my theme without setting it manually for every single button?

The Compose model is for you to create a design system. You create your own wrapper composables (e.g., FmButton()) around base composables (e.g., Button()) that implement your design rules. You then use your wrapper composables everywhere. Material3 is a design system, and you can refine it somewhat by configuring MaterialTheme in addition to controlling other aspects via wrapper functions.

@CommonsWare Yes, I understand the possibility of creating a custom wrapper, but does it make sense to do so when the behavior I want is the standard one for the base element and not for a specific purpose?

Behavior is only one criterion for creating wrapper functions in Compose. Design is another. Quite a bit has been written about design systems in Compose, from the documentation to public posts and presentations.
